# How to compare power of two relations?

Tags: spss, statistical-power

I have a case control study. Effect of A and B on C was calculated. C is a dependent variable (cases have C and controls havnot C defined as 1/0). A and B both are continuous  quantitavie variables. Result of calculations show A and B have statistically significant relationship (effect) on C ( using independent samples t yest). both P values of A-C relation and B-C relation was lower than 0.05. How can I know which of A or B has stronger relationship with C? (which one of A or B cause C more than another one?)